# Who decides the casing of newly coined words?

Tags: orthography, capitalization, camel-case

We are creating a product which is online hosted CMS solution (something like WordPress), and we want to call it **Site Pack**. However, there are places where we need to join these words together (like the logo for example). How we should case the joined word? There are many options available:

1. SitePack
2. Sitepack
3. sitepack

Which casing is correct? Who decides the casing of newly coined words? Do we have autonomy in determining the casing of the name of our product, or should we consult somewhere for that?

Comment: OT but you may also want to consider search engine selectivity in deciding whether to join the words.

Answer (score 5):

**Site Pack** isn't really a newly coined word, but the name of your product. Therefore you can choose whatever casing you like.

The design of your logo is also entirely up to you. There are many cases of companies whose logo is one case, but their chosen casing for the written text is different, for example Facebook and Twitter.

However, I'd advise to keep it simple and use Site Pack for both text and logo. Some companies can get away with things like iPlayer, but if you have different ways of writing it, people will sometimes get it wrong.

Comment: You may find, from a legal/PR standpoint, that rendering it as "SitePack" is better for the purposes of *establishing a trademark*; common English words without decoration tend not to do very well here, but portmanteaus and other such run-together constructs do.

Comment: @Karl: I don't think even Apple Corp. could successfully claim ownership of something like *SitePack*. They had a damned good try with *AppStore*, but [in the end they lost](http://www.t3.com/news/apple-app-store-legal-battle-sees-amazon-trump-apple)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Apple have an App Store, not AppStore, and I'm sure they've not given up the fight yet.

Comment: Apple *rarely* give up - or lose, making Amazon and Nokia members of a very exclusive [winners' club](http://english.aljazeera.net/business/2011/06/20116148184938474.html)